# How cellValueFactory() and cellFactory() works? and what is the difference between them?

Tags: javafx

I want to understand about these methods `cellValueFactory();` and `cellFactory();`

**When they invoked?**

**What is the purpose of them?**

**How they works?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both factories are used by the `TableView` (or more precisely it's `Skin`).

The `TableCell` ui element is created using the **`cellFactory`** when the `TableView` determines it needs a cell to display it's data. The data(=`item`) displayed in the cell may change (scrolling, modification of a `TableView` item). The `item` displayed in the `TableCell` is determined by the `TableView` using the **`cellValueFactory`**. The `TableView` determines which of it's items needs to be displayed in a given cell and uses the `cellValueFactory` get an `ObservableValue` that contains the instance.

The `cellFactory` can be used to customize the look of the cells in the table, but often this is not necessary, since the default `cellFactory` simply uses the `toString` method of it's items to get the `String` to display.

`cellValueFactory` is used to "select" a certain part of the items of the `TableView`, that should be displayed in a given column.

In this example you can also see a case of modifying the `TableView` item properties.

```
commit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Person p = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
        p.setName(name.getText());
        Double value = sizeFormatter.getValue();
        p.setSize(value == null ? -1d : value);
    }

});
```

What happens when the `Button` is clicked is the following:

1. The properties are modified, which notifies the listener the `TableView` has added to the `ObservableValue`s returned by the `cellValueFactory`s.
2. The `TableView` updates the items of the `TableCell`s in the row containing the item that was modified; the `updateItem` method is invoked with the new value. In this case the default factory is used, so `updateItem` simply sets `item.toString()` as new text.

Comment: After reading your given links I want to ask a question that what is the order of executing of `cellvaluefactory` and `cellfactory` methods? suppose I'm assigning property to `cellValueFactory();` and also modify tablecell by `cellFactory();` which value will be in table cell? the value by cellValueFactory()? or by cellFactory();?

Comment: The `updateItem` method of the `TableCell` is responsible for the appearance of the `TableCell`, so this one has precedence. But you should make the appearance depend on the value, i.e. change the `TableCell` depending on the `item` in the `updateItem` method. In this case both the `cellValueFactory` and the `cellFactory` are responsible for the appearance.If the value returned by `cellValueFactory` properly notifies listeners of changes,it simply doesn't matter when a change happens, since changing the tableview item as well as modifying the property of this item trigger updates of the cell.

Comment: Can you update your answer with an example of this? I'm not understanding it properly. Which method's value will be in Tablecell? and if we modify `TableCell` with `cellFactory` then we not need to use `cellValueFactory` ?

Comment: @Nothing: A `CellDataFeatures` object containing a item from `TableView.getItems()` will be passed to the `cellValueFactory`. This results in a `ObservableValue`. This object wraps the value that is used in the `TableCell`; furthermore it enables the `TableView` to listen to changes of the wrapped value. BTW: you shouldn't leave the `cellValueFactory` `null`, unless you're just displaying something that does not depend on the data. Otherwise it's rather complicated to get access to the data.

Comment: Now it makes more sense. Just last thing I searched allot and unable to find the exact sources to understand working of each part of tableview. from where you learnt this? can you give me reference which is describing each point of `TableView` , `cellFactory`, `cellValueFactory` and all other related to this one?

Comment: I don't really know where exactly I learned this, but in most cases [the javadocs are pretty helpful](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html), but there is also [oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm) which I don't remember exactly how helpfull it was in this case... Also an understanding of JavaFX properties and how they are used in the API helps...

Comment: You are awesome. Great helper. Thanks a lot.