# How to use setCellValueFactory and setCellFactory?

Tags: javafx

1. How do we use setCellValueFactory and setCellFactory?
2. What's difference between them?

Comment: This isn't really the correct place to ask for an entire tutorial. Perhaps http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-cell-renderer/ is useful.

Comment: Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/toc.htm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How cellValueFactory() and cellFactory() works? and what is the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803759/how-cellvaluefactory-and-cellfactory-works-and-what-is-the-difference-betwe)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the documentation :

**setCellValueFactory**

The cell value factory needs to be set to specify how to populate all cells within a single TableColumn. A cell value factory is a Callback that provides a TableColumn.CellDataFeatures instance, and expects an ObservableValue to be returned. The returned ObservableValue instance will be observed internally to allow for immediate updates to the value to be reflected on screen.

**setCellFactory**

The cell factory for all cells in this column. The cell factory is responsible for rendering the data contained within each TableCell for a single table column.
By default TableColumn uses the default cell factory, but this can be replaced with a custom implementation, for example to show data in a different way or to support editing.

Resource :http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/toc.htm and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellFactory-javafx.util.Callback-

Comment: I think this is quite difficult for me. I don't really understand callback class and how observablevalue funcions. It's better to provide examples. Thanks for help anyway.